# Pass job parameters to filter in spring integration ftp:inbound-channel-adapter

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-batch, spring-integration

I have defined a ftp:inbound-channel-adapter which will be triggered by a job and a custom filter which checks if filename matches a pattern and also if it was not processed before for the particular job.

So this requires that the jobname be available to the FTP filter. Is there a way by which this can be passed to the filter? Also is there a way to add jobname as a header to messages emitted by the ftp adapter?

```
<int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter
    local-directory="${data.dir}" session-factory="ftpClientFactory"
    channel="ftpOutputChannel" remote-directory="${ftp.data.directory}"
    filter="ftpFilter">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="50000" />
    <!--This will be replaced by a trigger job -->
</int-ftp:inbound-channel-adapter>

<beans:bean class="com.example.ftp.FtpFilter"
    id="ftpFilter"></beans:bean>
```

com.example.ftp.FtpFilter

```
public class FtpFilter implements FileListFilter<FTPFile> {

    public List<FTPFile> filterFiles(FTPFile[] files) {
        String validRegex = FileFilterStrategy.getValidTarGzRegex();
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
            String name = file.getName();
            if(name.matches(validRegex) && !isProcessed(jobName, name)){
                retval.add(file);
            }
        }
        return retval ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just get a reference to the filter and change some property on it.

There's currently no way to modify the headers in the way you describe; you could play some tricks in the filter using a `ThreadLocal`.

However, for these "event driven" scenarios, I generally recommend using an [outbound gateway](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ftp.html#ftp-outbound-gateway) to fetch the file(s) rather than the inbound channel adapter.

It gives you much more control - you can `get` (or `mget`) a pattern, or `ls` the remote directory and decide yourself which file(s) to `get`.

Also see the [ftp gateway sample app](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp) which uses `ls`, `get` and `rm` gateways.

Comment: But the filter is shared between different jobs, so setting property is not an option. Btw how does ls/mget give more control...we can list a directory and decide which files to get using a filter too, as in the question? Will look at outbound gateway though and revert back.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right, ended up using outbound gateway and ThreadLocal for accessing job property in ftpFilter.